# Call Parent function in Reactjs (Activate Drawer in menu item click on Material-ui)

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, material-ui

I try to activate the drawer when a user clicks a menu iten but my solution don't work. Can you help me, please?

Parent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// Import Appbar
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import LeftMenu from './Left_menu';

class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {open: false};
  }
  handleToggle() {
    this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
  }

  handleClose() {
      this.setState({open: false});
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <AppBar
        title="Log"
        onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this.handleToggle.bind(this)}
        />
        <Drawer
          docked={false}
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})}
        >
          <LeftMenu handleClose={this.handleClose} />
        </Drawer>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Header;
```

Child

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

class LeftMenu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <MenuItem onTouchTap={(event) => this.props.handleClose(event)}>Menu Item</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onTouchTap={(event) => this.props.handleClose(event)}>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LeftMenu;
```

I receive a message: TypeError: this.setState is not a function

I'm using Meteor + React + MaterialUI

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't `setState` in `render`, take that logic out of `onRequestChange`, just like you have done with `handleToggle` and `handleClose`:

```
   <Drawer
      docked={false}
      open={this.state.open}
      onRequestChange={(open) => this.setState({open})} // this.handleRequest??
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

In Parent

```
<LeftMenu handleClose={this.handleClose.bind(this)} />
```

In Child

```
<MenuItem onTouchTap={this.props.handleClose}>Menu Item</MenuItem>
<MenuItem onTouchTap={this.props.handleClose}>Menu Item 2</MenuItem>
```

Thanks anyway.